# Clean up local branches when Pull Request closed and remote @{push} branch deleted

Tags: git, github, version-control

My GitHub / GitLab workflow is:

1. `git checkout -b refs/remotes/up/HEAD my-feature` (Note branch tracks upstream, not my fork's PR branch)
2. `git push` (I have `remote.pushdefault = fork` in my git config)
3. Merge PR in GitHub ([Refined GitHub](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/#editing-pull-requests) extension auto-deletes the fork `my-feature` branch after I merge).
4. `git fetch --all` deletes `fork/my-feature` tracking branch (I have `fetch.prune = true` in my git config).
5. I periodically run a custom `git branch-prune` to batch cleanup the local `my-feature` branch.

Previously I would have PR branches track `fork/my-feature` (the branch they pushed to) rather than `up/HEAD` (the branch I'm raising the PR against) but this makes some workflows annoying. Since discovering [`@{upstream}`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem) and [`@{push}`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtpushemegemmasterpushemempushem) via [Magit's docs](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/The-Two-Remotes.html#The-Two-Remotes), I've switched to the above. Everything works great, except my `branch-prune` alias no longer works:

```
# Delete orphaned local branches.
branch-prune  = "!git fetch --prune && git branch -vv | awk '/: gone]/{print $1}' | xargs git branch -D"
```

I have a workaround, but I'm not sure how well it will work, and was hoping for something nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current workaround is adding the following script as an executable called `git-branch-prune` in my `$PATH`:

This seems to work for things merged with GitHub's `Rebase and Merge`, but I have yet to try it with `Squash and Merge` or `Create a Merge Commit`, I suspect they may break the `git cherry` check.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# `git branch-prune`: delete local branches whose commits have already been merged.

branches_to_prune=()

while read -r branch up_branch; do
  # If no remote-tracking branch with the same name in any remote,
  if [[ -z $(for remote in $(git remote); do git rev-parse --verify --quiet "$remote/$branch" ; done) ]] &&
    # and upstream branch exists,
    [[ -n "$up_branch" ]] &&
    # and upstream branch contains all the commits in fork branch.
    ! git cherry -v "$up_branch" "$branch" | grep -q '^+'; then
    # then we should delete the branch.
    branches_to_prune+=("$branch")
  fi
done <<<"$(git for-each-ref refs/heads --format='%(refname:short) %(upstream:short)')"

if [[ ${#branches_to_prune[@]} = 0 ]]; then
  echo "Nothing to prune."
  exit 0
fi

echo "Branches to delete: ${branches_to_prune[*]}"
read -rp "Continue? [Y/n] " choice

case $choice in
  N|n|no|No|NO) echo "Exiting..."; exit 1 ;;
esac

git branch -D "${branches_to_prune[@]}"
```